# Jupyter Notebooks wont load in a semicolon delimeted CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Im kind of new to python. Im trying to load in a semicolon delimited CSV, but it keep giving me errors when I set 'sep = ';''

I tried to do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Sophia Kohn\\Downloads\\wdwM-military-23.csv", sep =';')
```

It gave me an error, however when I set "sep = ','" it loads the CSV in, but the semicolons are all still there and I cannot do calculations/edit it beacuse all of the semicolons are still there. I checked the CSV and its definetly semicolon delimited so I am  very confused, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "It gave me an error" -- don't make us guess what the error was.  Please show us the full error message.

Comment: Also it would help to show us the first few lines of the csv file, if you can.

Comment: You should provide an example input that reproduces the problem you are seeing. If you are getting errors, provide the full error message including the stack trace.